# How to batch convert sentence lengths to masks in PyTorch?

Tags: nlp, pytorch

For example, from

```
lens = [3, 5, 4]
```

we want to get

```
mask = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Both of which are `torch.LongTensor`s.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way that I found is:

```
torch.arange(max_len).expand(len(lens), max_len) < lens.unsqueeze(1)
```

Please share if there are better ways!

Answer (score 13):

Just to provide a bit of explanation to the answer of @ypc (cannot comment due to lack of reputation):

> `torch.arange(max_len)[None, :] < lens[:, None]`

In a word, the answer uses `broadcasting` mechanism to implicitly `expand` the tensor, as done in the accepted answer. Step-by-step:

1. torch.arange(max_len) gives you `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`;
2. adding `[None, :]` appends 0th dimension to the tensor, making its shape `(1, 5)`, which gives you `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]`;
3. similarly, `lens[:, None]` appends 1st dimension to the tensor `lens`, making its shape `(3, 1)`, that is `[[3], [5], [4]]`;
4. By comparing (or doing anything like +,-,*,/, etc) a tensor of `(1, 5)` and `(3, 1)`, following the rule of `broadcasting`, the resulting tensor will be of shape `(3, 5)`, and the result values will be `result[i, j] = (j < lens[i])`.

Answer (score 4):

`torch.arange(max_len)[None, :] < lens[:, None]`

Comment: Try to give a description about your answer. It will help others to easily catch your code.Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer